# Problema con tipos DATE cuando parseo una lista de objetos con Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

Estoy haciendo una aplicación Java 8 que genera reports Jasper a través de una petición REST.

En este caso se le pasa un JSON con una lista de datos y Jackson lo deserializa.

El json que genero y que me está dando problemas es el siguiente:

```json
{
  "dataCollection": [
    {
      "idCE": 2021,
      "centro": "Cabañas",
      "NDocumento": "11111111A",
      "telefono1": "123456789",
      "telefono2": "234567891",
      "fechaNacimiento": "01/01/2000",
      "idSexo": 1,
      "paisNacimiento": "España",
      "email": "a@a.com",
      "localidadNacimiento": "Zaragoza",
      "nombreYApellidos": "Fulanito de Tal",
      "sexo": "varón",
      "provinciaNacimiento": "Zaragoza",
      "infoFamiliares": [],
      "materias": [],
      "documentos": [],
      "hash": "1234567890",
      "fechaTratamiento": "2022-03-03",
      "idCurso": 4,
      "nombreEnsenanza": "ESO",
      "infoFamiliares": [],
      "materias": [],
      "documentos": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Y lo leo del siguiente modo:

```java
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS);
        DatosInforme datosInforme = mapper.readValue(json, DatosInforme.class);
        return datosInforme;
```

El problema es con el campo fechaTratamiento que debería ser Date. (La fecha de nacimiento está como cadena en el report y no me afecta).

He probado diferentes cosas.

- Pasarlo como timestamp --> Me lo convierte a Long
- Pasar con diferentes formatos de fecha --> Me lo convierte a String

He visto en muchos sitios que lo solucionaban poniendo una anotación en el get de la propiedad que quiero que sea fecha pero en este caso no tengo, ya que lo que yo obtengo es una lista de Object, y después es otro (El report) el que hace el cast.

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo pasarle una fecha o cómo puedo configurar el mapper para que si la cadena sea en un formato determinado me lo coja como Date?

Muchas gracias